# With MS Sync Framework, can I sync between two DBs having different Sync scopes?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I've got the following scenario: 
In my system, it is possible that two data-stores (both SqlCe, or one is a server) will have different sync-scopes defined. In these circumstances, can I sync the two databases?

If it *is* possible to sync them, which scope will be used?

Thanks,
Assaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sync across them. When you create each sync provider, specify the scope for that particular database. The sync orchestrator doesn't care what scopes are in use and will sync between the scopes.

As to your second question, the local scope for each database will be used.